# Where can I store an image on Tkinter using grid() method?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am creating a login system with Tkinter and the grid() method but I have no idea where I can put the image. As i did not use classes and functions, it was pretty easy to embed the path for the image (`img = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Foto\\Haken.png")` `img1 = img.subsample(10,10)`, but, since I am new in Python, I don´t really know where to put the path in this code when the code is more organized. Here is what I tried:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class Login_system(Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent 
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        
        self.parent.title("Login System Prova")

        Label(text = "Surname").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
        Label(text = "Your Password").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
        Label(text = "Your E-Mail").grid(row=2, column=0,sticky=W, pady=2)
        Entry().grid(row = 0, column=1, pady=2)
        Entry().grid(row = 1, column=1, pady=2)
        Entry().grid(row = 2, column=1, pady=2)
        Entry().grid(row = 3, column=1, pady=2)
        Checkbutton(text = "Keep me on-line").grid(row = 4, sticky = W, columnspan= 1)
        
        


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("200x150+400+300")
    root.resizable(True, True)
    global image
    image = Frame.PhotoImage(file = r"C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Foto\\Haken.png")
    app = Login_system(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Python\GUI APP\login_system_new.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Python\GUI APP\login_system_new.py", line 34, in main
    image = Frame.PhotoImage(file = r"C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Foto_Marco\\Haken.png")
AttributeError: type object 'Frame' has no attribute 'PhotoImage'
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Have you got any suggestion? I would like to put the image on the far right column.

Comment: Remove `Frame.`, just `PhotoImage(file=...)`.

Comment: I tried it. It gives me no error back but when the window appears, there is no image at all.

Comment: Your code does not put the image into the window.  You need either a `Label` or a `Canvas` to show the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is part of the `Login_system`, then it is better put it inside the class.  Also you forget to specify the parent of widgets inside the class, so the widgets will be children of `root` instead.

Also avoid importing modules like below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

In this case, you cannot use some of the widgets from `tkinter` because they are override by those from `ttk`.

Below is a modified sample based on your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Login_system(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Login System Prova")

        ttk.Label(self, text="Surname").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Your Password").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Your E-Mail").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)
        ttk.Entry(self).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2)
        ttk.Entry(self).grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2)
        ttk.Entry(self).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=2)
        ttk.Entry(self).grid(row=3, column=1, pady=2)
        ttk.Checkbutton(self, text="Keep me on-line").grid(row=4, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=2)

        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Foto\\Haken.png").subsample(10,10)
        ttk.Label(self, image=self.image).grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=5, padx=(20,0))

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    #root.geometry("200x150+400+300")
    #root.resizable(True, True)
    app = Login_system(root)
    app.pack(fill='both', expand=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```